# Why is this answer considered a proper answer without solving the question, even partially?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation

I wonder, why is the answer given to my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102333/sequentially-importing-obj-files-becomes-drastically-slow-very-quickly) from *dr. Sybren* a valid answer? I flagged the answer but it has not been removed. I argue that this is not proper way of answering a question. I believe that a person who wants to answer a question needs to make sure that his/her answer really works, at least to some extend. However, the answer to my question not only does not work but the author of the answer argues with me on why I did not appreciate him. I just told him he needs to make sure his answer work and that's it! I was thinking that compiling Blender and using it as a module might be causing some weird issues on my side. That is exactly why I asked him to make sure his code works and I provided one obj file for him to do that (he could have done it via copying the obj file many times. *dr. Sybren*'s answer might work in another context or question where someone might have asked a question like *how to remove blocks more efficiently or properly?* but definitely not for my question. He could have instead posted a comment about what he posted in length, as an answer.

Although I appreciated him answering my question but I just got a bit upset cause he was literally sure that his answer is the answer to my question, without testing his code. He says I wrote things using my mobile phone but again, this is his fault not my fault. He needs to make sure his answer works (again, at least given the information provided) what does writing an answer on a mobile phone has do to with me? (how come he was write such a long answer on a mobile phone anyways, that I don't know)

Anyways, I thought I should bring my case to the judges here :) I already flagged the answer and my request has been rejected I think. Of course, I totally agree that people have different biases and opinions (including admins) but I'm not sure if one of the admins up-voted *dr. Sybren*'s answer after I flagged it and not mine; my answer clearly solves the issue and his does not in any way and even partially. If that has been the case, then I believe that this also undermines the quality of the way admins review things and they should pay more attention. This does not help improve the quality of the website in the long run :)

Thanks for consideration and sorry for my frank tone; I absolutely do not have any bad intentions of writing these things here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's look at what it means when you flag an answer as **Not an Answer**. The flagging dialogue reads:

> **not an answer**
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

It appears to me that this answer *does* attempt to answer the question. Even if it didn't provide a solution for you, it is still a valid **attempt to answer**. This is why this answer should remain up.

From [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/357942):

> Do not use this flag when:
>
> - The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it

Basically, it comes down to the fact that Stack Exchange answers are on the internet forever. The questions and answers on a Stack Exchange site aren't just for the asker, they are for anybody else needing help who might find it in the future. In general, even if an answer didn't work for you, as long as it is good-quality, it may help someone else with a problem that has similar symptoms, and should remain up.

Comment: I think I was wrong about what an answer means then. Thank you so much for clarification and I apologize if I made anyone feel bad in any way. Although I'm pretty new to Blender but my intention was only and only to help the community and as noiseless as possible

Answer (score 3):

For the record I did not vote on any of the posts in question - your question, or dr. Sybren's answer. (I did however UV your meta question here).

An admin did not handle your flag, because we are mods. :)
Really though, none of the three mods touched your flag. When you flag something as "not an answer" it goes through the review queue, and if handled there a mod will never see it. [Look](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/52456) for yourself. Neither of the users who rightly said it "looks ok" are mods.

Now on to what would of happened if a mod got to your flag - we would have declined it.
Flags are not for "wrong" answers. You down vote answers that do not answer the question, or are unhelpful.

> Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.
>
> You can downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are still answers, so you should not flag them.

[meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/278094) and [SO.meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/3220986)

Comment: Yes things are clear for me now. I had the wrong assumption about how an answer should be. This might be because of the bad impression I have got in the past from StackOverflow. I got punished a couple of times for posting an answer which was not solving the issue, at least to some extent .

Comment: I did not mean that moderators reviewed my flag. I actually did not know that *Mr Zak* and *batFINGER* reviewed my flag either. I apologize them if I conveyed anything bad.

Comment: @Amir SO can seem ruthless to new users. As much as I wish every answer were 100% helpful, that is just not the case, and that is why we have the UV *and* DV buttons.